# Почему все кол беки boost Asio выполняются в одном потоке, хотя io_context запущен в нескольких потоках?

Tags: c++, многопоточность, boost, асинхронность, boost.asio

В коде ниже представлен асинхронный сервер, который принимает сообщение от клиента, печатает сообщение в консоль, отправляет клиенту сообщение ok и сново слушает сокет. На каждом шаге я вывожу id потока, и это id всегда = 1. Я запускаю обработку в 10 потоках, но обработка все равно проходит в одном потоке, как это исправить?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <memory>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/thread.hpp>


using boost::asio::ip::tcp;

class Session {
private:
    tcp::socket sock;
    std::string message;
    uint16_t maxMessageLength;
private:
    Session(boost::asio::io_context& context, uint16_t maxMessageLength);
public:
    typedef std::shared_ptr<Session> SessionSharedPtr;
public:
    static SessionSharedPtr CreateNewSession(boost::asio::io_context& context, short messageLength = 2048);
    void ReceiveMessage(std::function<void(const boost::system::error_code&, size_t)>);
    void SendMessage(std::string message,
                     std::function<void(const boost::system::error_code&, size_t)> handler);
    std::string& GetMessage();
    tcp::socket& GetSocket();
    ~Session();
};

Session::Session(boost::asio::io_context &context, uint16_t maxMessageLength) : sock(context)
{
    this->maxMessageLength = maxMessageLength;
    message.resize(maxMessageLength);
}

Session::SessionSharedPtr Session::CreateNewSession(boost::asio::io_context &context, short messageLength) {
    return Session::SessionSharedPtr(new Session(context, messageLength));
}

Session::~Session() {
    sock.close();
}

std::string &Session::GetMessage() {
    return message;
}

tcp::socket &Session::GetSocket() {
    return sock;
}

void Session::ReceiveMessage(std::function<void(const boost::system::error_code&, size_t)> handler) {
    sock.async_read_some(boost::asio::buffer(message, maxMessageLength), handler);
}

void
Session::SendMessage(std::string messageToSend, std::function<void(const boost::system::error_code &, size_t)> handler) {
    sock.async_write_some(boost::asio::buffer(messageToSend, messageToSend.length()), handler);
}



boost::asio::io_context context;
tcp::acceptor acceptor(context, tcp::endpoint(tcp::v6(), 8000));

void acceptHandle(Session::SessionSharedPtr session, const boost::system::error_code& err){
    session->ReceiveMessage([=](const boost::system::error_code& err, size_t byte){
        std::cout << "thread_id(receive): " << boost::this_thread::get_id << std::endl;
        if (err)
            std::cout << "fail receive" << std::endl;
        else {
            std::cout << byte << std::endl;
            std::cout << session->GetMessage();;
        }
    });
    session->SendMessage("ok", [](const boost::system::error_code &err, size_t byte) {
        std::cout << "thread_id:(send) " << boost::this_thread::get_id << std::endl;
        if (err)
            std::cout << "fail send" << std::endl;
        else{
            std::cout << "send: " << byte << std::endl;
        }
    });
    auto newSession = Session::CreateNewSession(context);
    std::cout << "thread_id:(accept) " << boost::this_thread::get_id << std::endl;
    acceptor.async_accept(newSession->GetSocket(), std::bind(acceptHandle, newSession, std::placeholders::_1));
}


int main() {
    Session::SessionSharedPtr session = Session::CreateNewSession(context);
    acceptor.async_accept(session->GetSocket(), std::bind(acceptHandle, session, std::placeholders::_1));
    const size_t threadNum = 10;
    boost::thread_group threads;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < threadNum; i++){
        threads.create_thread([](){
            context.run();
        });
    }
    threads.join_all();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: *"я вывожу id потока"* - `<< boost::this_thread::get_id <<` выводит результат каста указателя в bool

Comment: @user7860670, а как вывести по нормальному?

Comment: добавить круглые скобки, чтобы получился вызов функции get_id